# Move to previous input on keydown using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to move to the next inputbox with javascript whenevever the maxlength of an inputbox is reached.
When the backspace key is pressed I want to clear the current inputbox and move to the previous one.

This is kind of working. Except whenever I press the backspace key it goes to the previous inputbox but doesn't clear the one I was currently on.

Example;

```js
var elts = document.getElementsByClassName('test')
Array.from(elts).forEach(function(elt){
  elt.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || elt.value.length == 1) {
      // Focus on the next sibling
      elt.nextElementSibling.focus()
    }
    if( event.keyCode == 8)
      {
        if (elt.previousElementSibling != null)
        {
            elt.previousElementSibling.focus();
        }
      }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 1em;
}

.field {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test" id="0" maxlength="1"/>
<input type="text" class="test" id="1" maxlength="1"/>
<input type="text" class="test" id="2" maxlength="1"/>
<input type="text" class="test" id="3" maxlength="1"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
var elts = document.getElementsByClassName('test')
Array.from(elts).forEach(function(elt) {
  elt.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13 ||
        event.keyCode !== 8 && elt.value.length === Number(elt.maxLength)
    ) {
      // Focus on the next sibling
      elt.nextElementSibling.focus()
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
      elt.value = '';
      if (elt.previousElementSibling != null) {
        elt.previousElementSibling.focus();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.field {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test" id="0" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="test" id="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="test" id="2" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="test" id="3" maxlength="1" />
```

Comment: 1) Enter a digit in the first box. 2) Press backspace.  Cursor ends up in the second box.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. I added "&& event.keyCode != 8) " to first if-statement to prevent it going back to the second inputbox when u press backspace in the first inputbox.

Comment: @MikeM Yes you're correct, I had to be more clear it wasn't supposed to go back haha. But thanks for giving me the solution.

Comment: I would imagine that when you're in the first box, moving to any box after pressing backspace is not necessary.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I agree. I've added the OP's solution to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

using `key` instead of `keyCode`

> *`key`* is what the user intends to see *(holds shift or capslock for "A", or not for "a")*

and take advantage of the method `getAttribute`

> *`getAttribute`* method of the Element interface returns the value of a specified attribute on the element.

also I've used [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
and
[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid  error if a previous element doesn't exist *nullish (null or undefined)*

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
Array.from(inputs).forEach(function (input) {
  input.addEventListener("keydown", keyhandler);
});
function keyhandler(e) {
  let { key } = e;
  let max = this.getAttribute("maxlength");
  if (key == "Backspace") {
    this.value = "";
    this?.previousElementSibling?.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (key == "Enter" || this.value.length >= max) {
    this.nextElementSibling.focus();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
.field {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test" id="0" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="test" id="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="test" id="2" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="test" id="3" maxlength="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the value of the input equal to an empty string?
Like that: `elt.setAttribute(value, '')`

Source:

[input element, look up for attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

[js method for attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)